# Unexpected msi-Setup crash on server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, msi

I am encountering the problem that I have an installer which works fine on other server 2003 enviroments but crashes on this one. My researches have lead me to the problem of installing IIS 6.0 - I don´t have the possibility to isert a disk.

**What I tried to solve this**

-> I got an ISO of Server 2003 and extracted the I386 folder, selected in the Setup.
   Result: Installing continued, said it was successfull, but IIS is not installed afterwards.

-> Reboot the enviroment after the setup.
   Result: Nothing changed.

-> Mounting the ISO and selecting it this way.
   Result: For some reason I am not able to mount on my enviroment.

-> Creating a logfile and try to read it.
    Result: I´m not that good at analyzing log files but i didn´t see anything.

**MSI Log-File**

```
=== Verbose logging started: 22.12.2014  11:17:56  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 

4.05.6002.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:57:008]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:57:008]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:57:008]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\MESOLager.Setup.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:57:040]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:58:446]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\MESOLager.Setup.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:58:446]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:58:446]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\MESOLager.Setup.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:58:883]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\MESOLager.Setup.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:055]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:055]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:071]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:071]: Original package ==> C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\MESOLager.Setup.msi
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:071]: Package we're running from ==> C:\DOKUME~1\ADMINI~1.TES\LOKALE~1\Temp\1\94dd6.msi
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:071]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{A069D9E3-21BE-402D-83BA-8264C1371733}'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:071]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:290]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:962]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 1
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:962]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{A069D9E3-21BE-402D-83BA-8264C1371733}'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'C:\example.log'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Command Line: CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=1324 
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{B22416FA-1B3C-4A71-890A-E7F7500AC479}'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{A069D9E3-21BE-402D-83BA-8264C1371733}'
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{A069D9E3-21BE-402D-83BA-8264C1371733}'
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Package name extracted from package path: 'MESOLager.Setup.msi'
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Package to be registered: 'MESOLager.Setup.msi'
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ALLUSERS property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 1
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: Running product '{A069D9E3-21BE-402D-83BA-8264C1371733}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '1324'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Anwendungsdaten
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Favoriten
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Netzwerkumgebung
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Eigene Dateien
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Druckumgebung
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Recent
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\SendTo
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Vorlagen
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Anwendungsdaten
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Lokale Einstellungen\Anwendungsdaten
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:17:59:977]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Eigene Dateien\Eigene Bilder
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:024]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Startmenü\Programme\Verwaltung
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:024]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Startmenü\Programme\Autostart
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:024]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Startmenü\Programme
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:024]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Startmenü
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:024]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Desktop
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:024]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Startmenü\Programme\Verwaltung
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:040]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Startmenü\Programme\Autostart
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:040]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Startmenü\Programme
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:040]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Startmenü
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:040]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:040]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Vorlagen
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:040]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:040]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:446]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:446]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:446]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:446]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\DOKUME~1\ADMINI~1.TES\LOKALE~1\Temp\1\94dd6.msi'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:446]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\MESOLager.Setup.msi'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:446]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:446]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:446]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\'.
MSI (c) (2C:B8) [11:18:00:493]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionHandler property. Its value is '4.05'.
=== Protokollierung gestartet: 22.12.2014  11:18:00 ===
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:524]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PatchPackage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:524]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:524]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:524]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:524]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:524]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:524]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ActionText 3: -2147287038 
Aktion 11:18:00: INSTALL. 
Aktion gestartet um 11:18:00: INSTALL.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:633]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:633]: Running UISequence
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:633]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:00:633]: Doing action: DIRCA_CheckFX
Aktion 11:18:01: DIRCA_CheckFX. 
Aktion gestartet um 11:18:01: DIRCA_CheckFX.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:01:665]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'DIRCA_CheckFX' 
MSI (c) (2C:70) [11:18:01:977]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\DOKUME~1\ADMINI~1.TES\LOKALE~1\Temp\1\MSI8.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckFX
MSI (c) (2C:AC) [11:18:02:008]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (2C:AC) [11:18:02:008]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (2C:AC) [11:18:02:008]: Connected to service for CA interface.
Aktion beendet um 11:18:03: DIRCA_CheckFX. Rückgabewert 3.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:03:446]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Aktion 11:18:03: FatalErrorForm. 
Aktion gestartet um 11:18:03: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:03:712]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 
Information 2898. For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
Bei der Installation dieses Pakets ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten. Es liegt eventuell ein das Paket betreffendes Problem vor. Der Fehlercode ist 2826. Argumente: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
Bei der Installation dieses Pakets ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten. Es liegt eventuell ein das Paket betreffendes Problem vor. Der Fehlercode ist 2826. Argumente: FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
Bei der Installation dieses Pakets ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten. Es liegt eventuell ein das Paket betreffendes Problem vor. Der Fehlercode ist 2826. Argumente: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
Information 2898. For VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
Information 2898. For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 20 pixels height.
Aktion 11:18:03: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
MSI (c) (2C:10) [11:18:03:930]: Note: 1: 2731 2: 0 
Aktion beendet um 11:18:05: FatalErrorForm. Rückgabewert 1.
Aktion beendet um 11:18:05: INSTALL. Rückgabewert 3.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:05:383]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (2C:AC) [11:18:05:383]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {F619D988-51D2-40F0-BE31-6CE6E3C60509}
Property(C): SourceDir = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\
Property(C): DesktopFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Desktop\
Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Startmenü\Programme\
Property(C): VSDFrameworkVersion = v4.5.1
Property(C): VSDAllowLaterFrameworkVersions = False
Property(C): ProductName = MESOLager 3.0
Property(C): ProductCode = {A069D9E3-21BE-402D-83BA-8264C1371733}
Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1031
Property(C): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(C): ARPPRODUCTICON = _853F67D554F05449430E7E.exe
Property(C): SecureCustomProperties = NEWERPRODUCTFOUND
Property(C): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(C): VersionNT = 502
Property(C): VSDNETURLMSG = Dieses Setup erfordert die Version [1] von .NET Framework. Installieren Sie .NET Framework, und führen Sie Setup erneut aus. .NET Framework kann über das Internet bezogen werden. Möchten Sie es jetzt beziehen?
Property(C): VSDUIANDADVERTISED = Die angekündigte Anwendung wird nicht installiert, da dieser Vorgang möglicherweise nicht sicher ist. Wenden Sie sich an den Administrator, um die Benutzeroberflächenoption für die Installation des Pakets zu ändern.
Property(C): VSDNETMSG = Dieses Setup erfordert die Version [1] von .NET Framework. Installieren Sie .NET Framework, und führen Sie Setup erneut aus.
Property(C): VSDINVALIDURLMSG = Der angegebene Pfad '[2]' ist nicht verfügbar. Der Internet Information Server wird möglicherweise nicht ausgeführt oder der Pfad ist vorhanden und wird zu einem anderen Computer umgeleitet. Überprüfen Sie den Status des virtuellen Verzeichnisses im Internet Services Manager.
Property(C): VSDVERSIONMSG = Installationsfehler, da bereits eine neuere Version des Produkts installiert ist.
Property(C): AdminMaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(C): MaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(C): EulaForm_Property = No
Property(C): FolderForm_AllUsers = ME
Property(C): FolderForm_AllUsersVisible = 1
Property(C): ErrorDialog = ErrorDialog
Property(C): SFF_UpFldrBtn = UpFldrBtn
Property(C): SFF_NewFldrBtn = NewFldrBtn
Property(C): DefaultUIFont = VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400
Property(C): AdminEulaForm_Property = No
Property(C): WelcomeForm_NextArgs = EulaForm
Property(C): EulaForm_PrevArgs = WelcomeForm
Property(C): EulaForm_NextArgs = FolderForm
Property(C): FolderForm_PrevArgs = EulaForm
Property(C): FolderForm_NextArgs = ConfirmInstallForm
Property(C): ConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = FolderForm
Property(C): AdminWelcomeForm_NextArgs = AdminEulaForm
Property(C): AdminEulaForm_PrevArgs = AdminWelcomeForm
Property(C): AdminEulaForm_NextArgs = AdminFolderForm
Property(C): AdminFolderForm_PrevArgs = AdminEulaForm
Property(C): AdminFolderForm_NextArgs = AdminConfirmInstallForm
Property(C): AdminConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = AdminFolderForm
Property(C): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\example.log
Property(C): PackageCode = {B22416FA-1B3C-4A71-890A-E7F7500AC479}
Property(C): ProductState = -1
Property(C): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG
Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 1324
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(C): VersionMsi = 4.05
Property(C): WindowsBuild = 3790
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 2
Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 3
Property(C): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(C): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(C): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(C): System16Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system\
Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(C): TempFolder = C:\DOKUME~1\ADMINI~1.TES\LOKALE~1\Temp\1\
Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Programme\
Property(C): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Programme\Gemeinsame Dateien\
Property(C): AppDataFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Anwendungsdaten\
Property(C): FavoritesFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Favoriten\
Property(C): NetHoodFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Netzwerkumgebung\
Property(C): PersonalFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Eigene Dateien\
Property(C): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Druckumgebung\
Property(C): RecentFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Recent\
Property(C): SendToFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\SendTo\
Property(C): TemplateFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Vorlagen\
Property(C): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Anwendungsdaten\
Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Lokale Einstellungen\Anwendungsdaten\
Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Eigene Dateien\Eigene Bilder\
Property(C): AdminToolsFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Startmenü\Programme\Verwaltung\
Property(C): StartupFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Startmenü\Programme\Autostart\
Property(C): StartMenuFolder = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Startmenü\
Property(C): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(C): GPTSupport = 1
Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): Intel = 16
Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 4095
Property(C): VirtualMemory = 4722
Property(C): AdminUser = 1
Property(C): LogonUser = Administrator
Property(C): UserSID = S-1-5-21-3198675214-2609395963-351469231-500
Property(C): UserLanguageID = 1031
Property(C): ComputerName = Business
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 1031
Property(C): ScreenX = 1708
Property(C): ScreenY = 919
Property(C): CaptionHeight = 19
Property(C): BorderTop = 1
Property(C): BorderSide = 1
Property(C): TextHeight = 16
Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(C): ColorBits = 16
Property(C): TTCSupport = 1
Property(C): Time = 11:18:05
Property(C): Date = 22.12.2014
Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.1
Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 5.2.3790.3959
Property(C): Privileged = 1
Property(C): USERNAME = User
Property(C): COMPANYNAME = User
Property(C): DATABASE = C:\DOKUME~1\ADMINI~1.TES\LOKALE~1\Temp\1\94dd6.msi
Property(C): OriginalDatabase = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\MESOLager.Setup.msi
Property(C): SOURCEDIR = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator.TESTUMGEBUNG\Desktop\MESOLager Update\
Property(C): VersionHandler = 4.05
Property(C): UILevel = 5
Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
=== Protokollierung beendet: 22.12.2014  11:18:05 ===
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:05:462]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:05:462]: Produkt: SFTW 3.0 -- Installation fehlgeschlagen.

MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:05:462]: Das Produkt wurde durch Windows Installer installiert. Produktname: SFTW 3.0. Produktversion: 3.0. Produktsprache: 1031. Erfolg- bzw. Fehlerstatus der Installation: 1603.

MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:05:462]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:05:462]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (2C:D8) [11:18:05:540]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 22.12.2014  11:18:05 ===
```

How do I install IIS 6.0 without a disc? What else could crash the MSI-file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Microsoft is no longer supporting Server 2003 which means i can´t use .NET Framework 4.5.1. It is not possible to run this MSI on my enviroment.